# How to test a react component that reads from state

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing

I'm trying to test an instance method of my component. The method does some calculations based on the component's `state`. I know how to mock `setState` with `jest.spyOn` but I don't know how to set my test instance's state. `getByTestId("component-to-test").setState(state)` throws an error.

I'm using `react-native-testing-library` if that makes any difference.

(I could generate the desired state by simulating interactions with the component, but a unit test like this is not the place for UI events, right?)

Comment: Hi, you should probably not test the state itself but rather test if the component displays the correct state.

Comment: The entire point of react-testing-library, and by extension, react-native-testing-library is to *NOT* interact with internal implementation details, but rather, test the component more in a way a user would via interactions with the UI. This is the break from the Enzyme way of testing, which is all about manipulating state and props on mounted components.

Comment: @DrewReese, this is indeed my understanding of the library. I just figured that since this function is just processing data (mapping an array onto some objects) it should be tested as if it were not a part of a component at all – it’s a unit that should work regardless of any other implementation details around it. If it were outside of a component it might take arguments (easily testable of course), but inside a component it uses the state within the function code.

Comment: Sounds like a more appropriate pattern would be to write the function outside the component and pass it relevant parts of state as arguments?

Comment: You don't (and shouldn't) need to test javascript functions, i.e. array::map. Same goes for testing if the mapping function throws an error, unless it is an error *your* code specifically throws. It is likely a safe assumption that this "data" you are "mapping" is related to passed props and derived state, so as Domino987 pointed out, you should test that the component is rendering the correct output based on specific input.

Comment: **If** this "mapping" function is doing a bit more than simply mapping to an object and it needs some testing, then yes, factor it out into a utility function and test in isolation.

It may be beneficial at this point to provide a code example of your component, and your test(s). Perhaps better advice can be given.

Comment: Thanks for all your advice @DrewReese. I think that refactoring is how I'll do it. I like the idea of having pure, unit-testable functions do the real work while the component has impure functions that call the pure functions with `state`. Then I feel more comfortable "testing" those component methods in UI tests.

Comment: My pleasure. Small, single-purpose, pure functions are awesome and much easier to work with and test.